# Regarding double and triple pointers/double dimension arrays

Tags: c, pointers, pointer-to-pointer

So, i was playing with C pointers and pointer arithmetic since i'm  not entirely comfortable with them. I came up with this code.

```
char* a[5] = { "Hi", "My", "Name", "Is" , "Dennis"};
char** aPtr = a; // This is acceptable because 'a' is double pointer
char*** aPtr2 = &aPtr; // This is also acceptable because they are triple pointers
//char ***aPtr2 = &a // This is not acceptable according to gcc 4.8.3, why ?

//This is the rest of the code, the side notes are only for checking
printf("%s\n",a[0]); //Prints Hi
printf("%s\n",a[1]); //Prints My
printf("%s\n",a[2]); //Prints Name
printf("%s\n",a[3]); //Prints Is
printf("%s\n",a[4]); //Prints Dennis

printf("%s\n",*(a+0)); //Prints Hi
printf("%s\n",*(a+1)); //Prints My
printf("%s\n",*(a+2)); //Prints Name
printf("%s\n",*(a+3)); //Prints Is
printf("%s\n",*(a+4)); //Prints Dennis

printf("%s\n",*(*(aPtr2) +0)); //Prints Hi 
printf("%s\n",*(*(aPtr2) +1)); //Prints My // ap = a, *ap = *a, *(ap)+1 = *a+1 ?
printf("%s\n",*(*(aPtr2) +2)); //Prints Name
printf("%s\n",*(*(aPtr2) +3)); //Prints Is
printf("%s\n",*(*(aPtr2) +4)); //Prints Dennis
```

`char*** aPtr2 = &a` is not acceptable according to gcc 4.8.3, why?

Sorry forgot to add compiler warning:

> warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]

It maybe unclear what I'm trying to say, so I had to add this links:

- This is the code that works: http://ideone.com/4ePj4h. (line 7. commented out)
- This is the code that does not work: http://ideone.com/KMG7OS. (line 6. commented out)

Notice the commented out lines.

Comment: By "not acceptable", what do you mean? Please include the warning or error message.

Comment: Are you sure it breaks? http://ideone.com/KM516t  (Note that you are missing a semicolon and are reusing the name `aPtr2`)

Comment: The `ideone` link I posted compiled it fine for gcc-4.9.2. What compiler flags are you using?

Comment: Yeah i know i'm reusing the name, it was just commented out because i had to do the other way around to look at the pointer arithmetic. It does indeed break. this works http://ideone.com/4ePj4h, but this does not http://ideone.com/KMG7OS.

Comment: Ahhh, I thought you meant a compile time error! Yes, you'll get a segfault, I'll explain why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This comes from the way C treats arrays and addresses:

```
int a[5];
```

`a` is of the type `int * const`, true, meaning you can use it where a pointer is expected. However, on the stack the space for the pointer isn't allocated, only the space for the five ints. Meaning `a` is the same as `&a[0]`. This is all expected, but here comes the weird part:

`a` is the same as `&a`. This is because the pointer isn't stored anywhere, you can't get it's address. But instead of failing the compile, the C standard just says that they are the same, so some arithmetic will work.

However, since you are doing `char ***aPtr2 = &a;`, you are effectively doing `char ***aPtr2 = a;`, which is why you get a segfault. It is only a double pointer, not a triple one.

You can inspect all the values in the debugger to see it more clearly, or run a program such as:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *a[5] = { "Hi", "My", "Name", "Is" , "Dennis"};
    char **aPtr = a; 
    char ***aPtr2 = &aPtr;
    char ***aPtr3 = &a; 

    printf("%p %c\n", a, *a);
    printf("%p %p %c\n", aPtr, *aPtr, **aPtr);
    printf("%p %p %p %c\n", aPtr2, *aPtr2, **aPtr2, ***aPtr2);
    printf("%p %p %c\n", aPtr3, *aPtr3, **aPtr3);

    return 0;
}
```

which produces the output:

```
0xfff65578 H
0xfff65578 0x8048648 H
0xfff65574 0xfff65578 0x8048648 H
0xfff65578 0x8048648 H
```

---

EDIT: Another interesting thing is the function pointers are treated in the same fashion. `&func` is the same as `func`.

```
int add(int a, int b) { return a + b; }
typedef int (*PFUNC)(int, int);

PFUNC p1 = add;
PFUNC p2 = &add;
if (p1 == p2) 
     printf("Huh. %d, %d\n", (*p1)(1,2), p2(3, 4)); // the dereference is also optional
```

Answer (score 2):

`a` is the address of a buffer of 5 ptrs and is immutable (i.e. its a fixed ptr). If you allowed

```
char ***aPtr2 = &a;
```

then

```
*aPtr2 = &a[3];
```

would actually modify the address `a` (which is  verboten).